# How do you iterate through a python list of coordinates and change the y-axis accordingly?

Tags: python, arrays, list, coordinates

So I have been playing around with Python lists lately and come across a problem.
Which is:

I have created a two-dimensional list of 100 coordinates. So at each index, there is a list containing two values. Thus index [0] = [x,y] and so on.

I attempted to then set the values to represent a coordinate plane of sorts. Starting from -5 to 5. I managed to change to x values to fit. Making them go in a pattern like such: 
`[-5, y] [-4,y] [-3,y] [-2, y] [-1, y] ...` through to 5, for each set of 10 (to make 100).

My problem comes in when I try to change the y values to fit accordingly. 
As I want them to appear like: `[x,5][x,5][x,5][x,5][x,5]...` until the next row of 10, where'd they'd be `[x,4][x,4][x,4][x,4][x,4]` and so on.

Thus I want to know a way to iterate through a list, change a set amount of indexes to a specific value and then change the value for the next set amount of indexes.

Comment: Can you *show us* your desired output for, say, 20 rows?

Comment: Of course (Although I currently have an idea, although I cannot test it currently)              

[-5, 5], [-4, 5], [-3, 5], [-2, 5], [-1, 5], [0, 5], [1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5],
[5, 4], [-5, 4], [-4, 4], [-3, 4], [-2, 4], [-1, 4], [0, 4], [1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4]

Is this enough?

Comment: I think you should look into numpy for doing these kinds of operations much faster and simpler

Comment: `cords = [[y, x] for x in range(-5, 6) for y in range(-5, 6)]`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, try and use vectorised functions.

For example, via `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

n = 2

A = np.vstack((np.tile(np.arange(-5, 6), n),
               np.repeat(np.arange(5, 5-n, -1), 11))).T
```

Result:

```
array([[-5,  5],
       [-4,  5],
       [-3,  5],
       [-2,  5],
       [-1,  5],
       [ 0,  5],
       [ 1,  5],
       [ 2,  5],
       [ 3,  5],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 5,  5],
       [-5,  4],
       [-4,  4],
       [-3,  4],
       [-2,  4],
       [-1,  4],
       [ 0,  4],
       [ 1,  4],
       [ 2,  4],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 4,  4],
       [ 5,  4]])
```